# Копировать в буфер обмена из заблоченого input-а JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть `input type="text"`. Его нельзя изменить - стоит атрибут `disabled`. Рядом кнопка для его копирования. Как скопировать из этого input-а в буфер обмена? Я пробовал разные варианты -  ZeroClipboard и разные варианты которые находил в интернете, но они работают только если убрать атрибут `disabled`.

Comment: Можно вместо disabled, readonly попробовать.

Comment: @ModaL Спасибо, сработало.

Comment: @ModaL запиши как ответ, вопрос хороший